# JavaScript Set Default Value on Function Not Working?

Tags: javascript, html

Function in JS

```
    function punch(){
    var a,b,result;
    a=document.getElementById('n1').value;
    b=document.getElementById('n2').value;

    var x=parseInt(a);
    var y=parseInt(b);
    result=x+y;


     if (result===NaN)
     result =0;
```

I know this condtition is false and it gives output of x+y.   On empty fields it always return NaN value
    when change it to

```
if (result!==NaN)
 result=0;
```

Now it becomes true but it gives x+y also 0.

```
document.getElementById('n3').value=result;   
}
```

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" id="n1" placeholder="Value 1"/>
<input type="text" id="n2" placeholder="Value 2"/>
<button type="button" onClick="punch()">Click For Answer</button>
<input type="text" id="n3" placeholder="Answer"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing, including `NaN`, is ever `===` to `NaN`. In fact one way to test *for* `NaN` is to exploit that!

```
if (result !== result)
  result = 0; // must have been NaN!
```

You can also use `isNaN()`:

```
if (isNaN(result))
  result = 0;
```

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown yes I would use that preferentially; the first is just for illustration (though I've seen it used).

Comment: Pointy Thanks for help! just play little bit with variable (result !== result) and its become true